# Laravel Mail, Erro: Variável indefinida

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

Boa noite amigos,

Estou tendo um problema, quando tento passar as variáveis de um controle para o outro, ele acaba acusando que a variável "não foi definida":

**(Undefined variable: schedule)**

Não sei o que estou fazendo de errado, alguém poderia me ajudar? Preciso de uma luz rsrs...

---

*ScheduleController.php*

```
use App\Schedule;
use App\Mail\AgendamentoEpcSup;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

public function store(Request $request)
        {
            $schedule = New Schedule();
            $schedule->user_id = $request -> input('user_id');
            $schedule->room_id = $request -> input('room_id');
            $data_str = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $request-> input ('date_choice'));
            $schedule->date = $data_str->format('Y-m-d');
            $schedule->hour_in = $request-> input('hour_in');
            $schedule->hour_out = $request-> input('hour_out');

            $schedule->save();

            $user = Auth::user();
            $user_email = Auth::user()->email;

            Mail::to($user_email)->send(new AgendamentoEpcSup($schedule, $user));

            return redirect()->route('schedules.index')->with('status', 'Novo agendamento criado, lembrando que cancelamentos só podem ser feitos com 12h de antecedência pelo sistema.');
        }
```

---

*AgendamentoEpcSup.php*

```
namespace App\Mail;

use App\User;
use App\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class AgendamentoEpcSup extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $schedule;
    public $user;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->schedule = $schedule;
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->markdown('emails.agendamento', compact('schedule', 'user'));
    }
}
```

---

Não sei pq os valores não estão sendo passados :/

Agradeço dês de já!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema:

Em `AgendamentoEpcSup.php`, no `__construct()`  você faz:

```
$this->schedule = $schedule
```

...mas não definiu $schedule em lugar nenhum, o erro só está informando o óbvio. Como é que o `__construct` vai saber o que é `$schedule`?

Se quer inicializar variáveis no construtor precisa de algo assim:

```
public function __construct($var1, $var2) // <-- Atenção aqui! Nós acrescentamos
                                          // duas variáveis para receber o que
                                          // foi enviado pelo new.
{
    $this->schedule = $var1;              // Agora sim, estamos usando algo que existe
    $this->user = $var2;
}
```

Que é para corresponder com a chamada:

```
AgendamentoEpcSup($schedule, $user)
```

Nota: usei `$var1` e `$var2` propositalmente, para você ver que os nomes dentro do `__construct()` independem dos nomes usados na chamada, mas fique à vontade para usar os nomes como quiser.

Comment: Noooooossa eu mereci HAHAHAHAHHAHAHA... Pior que eu revisei umas 10 vezes o códio e pra mim estava ok...  Mente cansada é complicado... Mas obrigadão pela ajuda... Possivelmente eu iria estar me questionando até agora rsrs... Na minha cabeça, como eu já havia declarado *public $schedule;*, eu estava achando que o *$this->* já estava puxando os valores HAHAHHAHAHA... Nossa, valeu mesmo...